# Wave speed question wave equation given in terms of exp

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

**Question**

A wave propagating  along the x axis . The displacement of the particles is along the Z axis at t=0 is given by Z= exp[-(x+2)^2] where x is in metres . At t=1  Z=  [-(2-x)^2] find the speed of the wave.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graphs of these two functions are like normal distribution functions and so have a bell shape.
What you need to do is find out how far the peak moves from $t=0$ to $1=1$.

Comment: that is what iam asking so iwould have to plot it all the way or there is some other method or formula

Comment: Look up normal distribution to see where the maximum occurs or sketch the graph.

Comment: look i really am unable to understand what do u mean by the normal distribution

Comment: Have a look at this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function